# Find Nth document based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query

If the total number of documents exceeds N, then fetch the Nth document. If that is less than N, then fetch the last document.

How to write a query for this?

One approach could be

```rb
N = 100
query = {} # some other conditions
Model.where(query).limit(N).to_a.last
# This is inefficient as it fetches all N documents

Model.where(query).limit(N).last
# This doesn't work since .last translates to .limit(1) and replaces .limit(N)

Model.where(query).skip(N-1).first
# this doesn't work when total number of documents is less than N


m = Model.where(query).skip(N-1).first
m = Model.where(query).last if !m
# This works but can we do it in a single query?
```

Comment: Any answer purely based on `mongo` is also appreciated

Comment: I don't believe you can do it in a single query. I wouldn't worry about performance if your app is relatively small. Tune later

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have N=21

```
var res= DB.collection.find().limit(21);

res[res.length-1] // which is equivalent to res.last
```

- if you have matched 10 records :
  then res will have 10 records and you will get res[9] which is last element when result size(10) is less then N(21)
- if you have matched 30 records : then res will have 21 records(as limit is N(21)) and you will get res[20] which is last element when result size(21) is less then N(21)
- if you have matched 21 records : then res will have 21 records(as limit is N(21)) and you will get res[20] which is last element when result size(21) is less then N(21)

Comment: thanks. I already know this method as i have mentioned although it is in ruby lang. The problem with this approach is that it fetches all the 21 documents, and this is a problem when N becomes large or individual document size is large

Comment: Okay how about below one?
var size=9

db.collection.find({}).skip((db.collection.find({}).limit(size).count(1)) - 1).limit(1)  
 Sorry i can just share the mongo shell command which works for your case.....
Logic here is to find and skip dymamically all  matched documents but 1.
In general what all you need is db.collection.find({}).skip(n-1 or total-1 if total is <n).limit(1)

Comment: I am sure you can easily convert above mongo shell snippet into equivalent ruby code :)